# Pyglet media queue is not clear after doing player.delete()

Tags: python, tkinter, pyglet

I am trying to play and stop the media. When I click on Stop the player is stopped and clear the selection in the list box. When I click on play button again the media is playing wherever I stopped the audio.
To make it clear the stop is working as a pause. it is not clearing the queue
here is my code. I don't want to change the pyglet library.

```
class Seekbar(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, parent, **options):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, options)
        self.parent = parent
        self.width = options['width']
        self.red_rectangle = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, fill="red")
        self.seekbar_knob_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/seekbar_knob.gif")
        self.seekbar_knob = self.create_image(
            0, 0, image=self.seekbar_knob_image)
        self.bind_mouse_button()


    def bind_mouse_button(self):
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_seekbar_clicked)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_seekbar_clicked)
        self.tag_bind(
            self.red_rectangle, '<B1-Motion>', self.on_seekbar_clicked)
        self.tag_bind(
            self.seekbar_knob, '<B1-Motion>', self.on_seekbar_clicked)

    def on_seekbar_clicked(self, event=None):
        if event.x > 0 and event.x < self.width:
            self.slide_to_position(event.x)

    def slide_to_position(self, new_position):
        self.coords(self.red_rectangle, 0, 0, new_position, new_position)
        self.coords(self.seekbar_knob, new_position, 0)
        self.event_generate("<<SeekbarPositionChanged>>", x=new_position)


class TestSeekBar():
    toggle_play_stop = itertools.cycle(["play", "stop"])

    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.bind("<<SeekbarPositionChanged>>", self.seek_new_position)
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.grid(row=1, pady=10, padx=10)
        c = Seekbar(
            frame, background="blue", width=360, height=10)
        c.grid(row=2, columnspan=10, sticky='ew', padx=5)
        self.add_file_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/add_file.gif")
        self.add_file = tk.Button(frame, image=self.add_file_image, command=self.add_file)
        self.add_file.grid(row=3)
        self.audio_list_box = tk.Listbox(frame)
        self.audio_list_box.grid(row=4)
        self.play_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/play.gif")
        self.stop_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/stop.gif")
        self.play_stop_btn = tk.Button(frame, image=self.play_image, command=self.play_stop)
        self.play_stop_btn.image = self.play_image
        self.play_stop_btn.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.audio_time = tk.Label(frame, text="00.00")
        self.audio_time.grid(row=1, column=2)
        of_label = tk.Label(frame, text="of")
        of_label.grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.audio_total_length = tk.Label(frame, text="00.00")
        self.audio_total_length.grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.player = pyglet.media.Player()
        root.mainloop()

    def seek_new_position(self, event):
        print("Dragged to x:", event.x)

    def add_file(self):
        audios = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
        for audio in audios:
            path = os.path.split(audio)
            audio = path[1]
            self.audio_list_box.insert(END, audio)
            self.path = f'{path[0]}/'
            print(self.path)

    def play_stop(self):
        action = next(self.toggle_play_stop)
        if action == "play":
            try:
                self.current_track_index = self.audio_list_box.curselection()[0]
            except IndexError:
                self.current_track_index = 0
            self.play()
        elif action == "stop":
            self.stop_play()

    def play(self):
        self.audio = self.audio_list_box.get(ACTIVE)

        self.play_stop_btn.config(image=self.stop_image)
        self.source = pyglet.media.load(self.audio)
        self.player.queue(self.source)
        self.get_audio_length()
        self.player.play()

    def stop_play(self):
        self.play_stop_btn.config(image=self.play_image)
        self.audio_list_box.selection_clear(ACTIVE)
        self.audio_total_length.config(text="00.00")
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        self.reset_player()

    def reset_player(self):
        self.player.pause()
        self.player.delete()

    def get_audio_length(self):
        self.get_audio_total_length = self.source.duration
        minutes, seconds = self.get_time_in_minute_seconds(self.get_audio_total_length)
        self.track_length_string = 'of {0:02d}:{1:02d}'.format(minutes, seconds)
        self.audio_total_length.config(text=self.track_length_string)

    def get_time_in_minute_seconds(self, time_in_seconds):
        minutes = int(time_in_seconds / 60)
        seconds = int(time_in_seconds % 60)
        return (minutes, seconds)

    # @property
    # def audio_length(self):
    #     try:
    #         return self.source.duration
    #     except AttributeError:
    #         return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    TestSeekBar()
```

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details. How do you run the Pyglet event loop? If you are not running the Pyglet event loop, you should avoid it.

Comment: i think i am not running pyglet event loop